# MVC 4 getting values of selected radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I'm just venturing out into the world of MVC (v4) and I'm having real trouble getting the actual selected values of a list of radiobutton lists. I'm pulling the data from an Umbraco database (but I guess the principle of what I'm trying to do will be the same) where there are list of questions with each question having a list of answers. I'll post everything that I've done so far in the hope that someone more intelligent than I could point me in the right direction:

Here's my content structure

[image]

My Model

```
namespace ICASolution.Models
{
    public class MultipleChoiceViewModel
    {
        public int iQuestionID { get; set; }
        public string zQuestionTitle { get; set; }
        public string zQuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<Answers> lAnswers { get; set; }

    }

    public class Answers
    {
        public int iAnswerID { get; set; }
        public string zAnswerText { get; set; }
        public bool bCorrect { get; set; }
        public string selectedAnswer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My surface controller:

```
namespace ICASolution.Controllers
{
    public class MultipleChoiceSurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        //
        // GET: /MultipleChoiceSurface/

        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return PartialView("MultipleChoice", new MultipleChoiceViewModel());
        //}
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Grade(MultipleChoiceViewModel model)
        {

            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var TestPage = Umbraco.Content(CurrentPage.Id);
            var questions = new List<MultipleChoiceViewModel>();

            foreach (var child in TestPage.Children)
            {
                var questionid = child.Id;
                var questiontitle = child.GetPropertyValue("questionTitle");
                var questiontext = child.GetPropertyValue("questionText");

                questions.Add(new MultipleChoiceViewModel { iQuestionID = questionid, zQuestionTitle = questiontitle, zQuestionText = questiontext, lAnswers = answerList(questionid) });

            }

            return PartialView("MultipleChoice", questions);
        }

        public List<Answers> answerList(int iMyQuestionID)
        {
            var questionPage = Umbraco.Content(iMyQuestionID);
            var answers = new List<Answers>();


            foreach(var child in questionPage.Children)
            {
                answers.Add(new Answers { iAnswerID = child.Id, zAnswerText = child.GetPropertyValue("answerTitle"), bCorrect =  child.GetPropertyValue("correctAnswer") });
            }

            return answers;
        }

    }
}
```

and finally my partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<ICASolution.Models.MultipleChoiceViewModel>


<div class="ethicsTestContainer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 noRPadding">
            @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<ICASolution.Controllers.MultipleChoiceSurfaceController>("Grade")) { 

                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p><strong>@item.zQuestionTitle</strong></p>
                            <p>@item.zQuestionText</p>

                            @{
                                foreach (var answerItem in item.lAnswers)
                                {
                                    <div class="radio radio-danger">
                                        @Html.RadioButton(answerItem.iAnswerID.ToString(), answerItem.iAnswerID, new { @type = "radio", @id = answerItem.iAnswerID, @name = item.iQuestionID })

                                        @*<input type="radio" name="@item.iQuestionID" id="@answerItem.iAnswerID" value="option1">*@
                                        <label for="@answerItem.iAnswerID">
                                            @answerItem.zAnswerText <span>&nbsp;</span>@answerItem.bCorrect
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
                    }


                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">CLICK HERE TO COMPLETE YOUR ETHICS TEST</button>
                </div>

            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything renders fine when displayed to the user:

[image]

But I just can't work out how to get the selections that the user has made on the HTTPPOST (basically I need to count the amount of correct answers that they have made).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are generating the controls for `MultipleChoiceViewModel` in a `foreach` loop with generates duplicate `name` attributes which cannot be bound to a collection (they do not include indexers) and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. You need to generate the controls in a `for` loop (or use a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `MultipleChoiceViewModel`)

You also need to move the `selectedAnswer` property to `MultipleChoiceViewModel` (not in `selectedAnswer`)

Using a `for` loop (the model must be `IList<MultipleChoiceViewModel>`)

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].iQuestionID) // for post back
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].zQuestionTitle)
  ... 
  foreach(var item in Model[i].lAnswers)
  {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].selectedAnswer, item.iAnswerID, new { id = item.iAnswerID })
    <label for="@item.iAnswerID">@item.zAnswerText</label>
  }
}
```

To use an `EditorTempate`, create a partial view in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` named `MultipleChoiceViewModel.cshtml`

```
@model yourAssembly.MultipleChoiceViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.iQuestionID)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.zQuestionTitle)
... 
foreach(var item in Model.lAnswers)
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.selectedAnswer, item.iAnswerID, new { id = item.iAnswerID })
  <label for="@item.iAnswerID">@item.zAnswerText</label>
}
```

and then in the main view,replace the `for` loop with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

The `EditorFor()` method will generate the html based on the template for each item in the collection.

Side notes: `RadioButtonFor()` generates `type="radio"` so adding a html for `@type = "radio"` is pointless. And NEVER override the `name` attribute when using html helpers

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Hi Stephen,
Firstly thanks for your time
Secondly you've lost me(!), to be honest I've had a right play about with some of the controls (as you can tell) and I ended up confusing myself.

I've moved the SelectedAnswer property inside the MultipleChoiceViewModel.

But following your code I'm getting an error on @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].iQuestionID)) of Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEumerable<ICASolution.Models.MultipleChoiceViewModel>'

Coming from WebForms this whole MVC feels like black magic so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No your model must be `IList<MultipleChoiceViewModel>` (see 3rd paragraph). If for some reason you cannot change it to `List<T>` then you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` for type of `MultipleChoiceViewModel`

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that part! Still the same error I'm afraid, I don't even know what a EditorTemplate is (!) Think I may be venturing too far down the rabbit hole too quickly here

Comment: Actually hold that thought (I may have been being more of an idiot than I normally am!)

Comment: Assuming you have now worked it out - i.e. its `@model List<ICASolution.Models.MultipleChoiceViewModel>` I will also update my answer a bit later to show the `EditorTemplate` option.

Comment: Hi mate, I think that I've sussed out the front end but if you could gimme a pointer as to how I actually get the selections in the controller that would be amazing. This is where (I thought) I was originally going wrong

Comment: If your POST method parameter is `List<MultipleChoiceViewModel>` (i.e to match the model in the view, then everything will be bound (at least every property that you have rendered a control form)

Comment: Christ now I'm confused!

Comment: Which part are you not understanding?

Comment: Think I've got it mate. I was expecting that because the view is a type of IList<ICASolution.Models.MultipleChoiceViewModel> then I was automatically expecting the HttpPost ActionResult method would receive this IList as a default parameter actually declaring the incoming parameter as IList<MultipleChoiceViewModel> is now showing me the selections that the user has made. Which is indeed what you told me I just didn't understand it! I think it's all good now apart from doing some HTML work (making sure people answer every question etc). You my friend have been a star

Comment: Just put a `[Required]` attribute on property `selectedAnswer` and include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].selectedAnswer)` - you will then get both client and server side validation

Comment: Mate you've been absolutely brilliant...can't thank you enough. Not sure which to mark as the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the radio buttons using below code:

```
<div class="mt-radio-inline">
  <label class="mt-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1_Chart"> Chart
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <label class="mt-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1_AnySize"> Any Size 
    <span></span>                                                
  </label>
</div>
```

And get the selected radio button value from code given below:

```
string q = form["q1"];
```

In above code form is the object of **FormCollection**

This will gives you a string of the selected radio button from a group.